Using lasso trim to create new geometries in Blender sculpt mode but failed
When I use Lasso Trim of join mode in Sculpt mode to create new geometries, I set them random color. But it seems geometries I created are in one geometry. I'm using blender 4.1
It appears geometries I created are the same color, and I can't switch between them with shortcut D, and I can't delete geometry by Edit Face Group either.
How do I fix this?

I've found the answer by myself. In blender 4.1 , the lasso trim of join mode does not create default face group. So, when we use lasso trim to create geometry, we need to mark its face group by Choose Face group tool, then we get a first face group. After that, when you use lasso trim to create new geometries, they will be different face groups. All geometries in different face groups can be removed by Edit Face Group tool.
